# How to make a queue manager default in a cluster

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a cluster named inventory with 4 queue managers defined london, paris, newyork, tokyo. If london and paris are the default queue managers which get messages, how can I make newyork and tokyo as default to receive and not allow clients to put messages on london and paris but they should still be in the cluster. can this be achieved with workload management ?

If there are any other solutions please let me know. All this should be done without making any changes on the client side.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Adding to T.Rob's suggestions here are couple of options you could take a look at:

1. Disable put on cluster queue instances in `london` and `paris`. So the messages will be distributed between `newyork` and `tokyo`.
2. Write a cluster workload balancing exit that will skip putting messages to cluster queues in `london` and `paris` and puts messages only to cluster queue instances in `newyork` and `tokyo`.

See [Writing and compiling cluster workload exits](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.doc%2Fqc10950_.htm) from the MQ 7 Documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to remember that WebSphere MQ clusters provide a context that tells queue managers how to talk amongst themselves.  Clients, on the other hand, are completely unaware of clusters.  Clients must be told specifically which queue managers to connect to.

In your case, when configuring the clients provide them with the connection details for `newyork` and `tokoyo` QMgrs and they won't connect to `london` or `paris`.  Assuming all these QMgrs are in a WebSphere MQ cluster, the messages from the clients will be able to resolve to clustered queues residing on `london` and `paris`.